# Create list of files in directory, apply (lapply) a custom function to each, and cbind results to new file

Tags: r, excel, lapply

rewrote in attempt to simplify my problem statement.

I am using R V1.3.959 and relatively new to R overall. I have a custom excel form, which means the objects are in various cells in excel and the variable is also in some cell.  I have over 1000 of these forms as product specs.  I read in only 1 file and created a function called tidy.form to pull data out and then cbind into new file as below.

```
read_customer_file = "C:/Users/..../FABRIC TECHNICAL SUBMISSION AGREEMENT J123abd.xlsx"

product_tech <- read_excel(read_customer_file, sheet = "Form") %>% clean_names()

#function for make form tidy
form.extract <- function(tidy.form) {
  
#extract the object / data point looking for but with entire column
fabric.supplier.name <- product_tech[c( 0,5)]
#extract the specific row in the column with the data point desired
fabric.supplier.name <- slice(fabric.supplier.name, 3,0)
#rename column to correct variable
colnames(fabric.supplier.name)[colnames(fabric.supplier.name) == "x5"] <- "fabric.supplier.name"

combine <- cbind(date, fabric.supplier.name, address)
return(combine)
}
```

Now I need a way to read in all of the xlsx files from a directory and do the same thing for each.

I figured out how to read the file names in through:

```
files <- list.files(path="C:/Users/me/productspecfolder", pattern="*.xlsx", full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE)
```

However I am stuck at how to loop / lapply through my list.files and apply the function tidy.form to each.

Any help would be so much appreciated!

Comment: What is `x`? It is not defined. Is it `tidy.form`? If so it needs to be `x` in the function call or `tidy.form` in the body of the function. The two must match.

Comment: Hello Justin. Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question.

Comment: You are passing `tidy.form` in the function and not using it anywhere? Please try to share a reproducible example along with expected output.